# Difference between variables in the init__() method

Tags: python, oop

I read similar topics on stackoverflow, but that was not enough for me.
Here are 3 block codes.
Block №1:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, odometer_reading):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = odometer_reading
```

Block №2:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0
```

Block №3:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, odometer_reading = 0):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = odometer_reading
```

What’s the difference between `odometer_reading` in parenthesis and not in parenthesis?
Is it only the ability to set a default value? When `odometer_reading` is in parenthesis (Block №1) we must to pass value into it as we create an object. But when `odometer_reading` is not in parenthesis and has a deafault value (Block №2) we mustn’t pass data into it as we create an instance of the Car class. Is that it? Or is there something more?

And what’s the difference between `odometer_reading` in Block №2 and Block №3 (if there is any)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, `odometer_reading` is a required argument and the caller must provide it.

In the second example, `odometer_reading` is not an argument and the caller must not provide it.  It always starts at zero.

In the third example, it is an optional argument.  The caller may provide it if they wish.  If not, it defaults to zero.

Comment: And ... this is precisely the same as any other python method.

Comment: Thank you for your simple but effective explanation. One more question. In the second example, odometer_reading is not an argument and the caller must not provide it - he must not provide it, but can he?

Comment: @Malpertui No.  In the second example, there is no such argument `odometer_reading `.  It cannot be provided.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you one more time ) I think I understood

Answer (score 1):

Block №2: Sets odometer_reading to 0 by default within the **init** method.
Block №3: Allows you to specify a default value for odometer_reading in the method signature, but you can override it during object instantiation if needed.

Comment: Thank you! Can I override odometer_reading from block #2 during object instantiation?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the three blocks of code is that in the block the `odometer_reading` is always be equal to the value provided through function call.

But in block 2, the value is always equal to 0. The value provided through function call(or simply parameters) is not used. In the case of third code block, if the value is not provided by the user then it will be equal to 0. It will use the value of `odometer_reading` if provided.

Comment: Thank you! So I can’t provide another value through function call in block№2?

Answer (score 1):

In block 1: While creating an instance of the class you are required to pass odometer_reading

In block 3: If you don't pass any value 0 will be set by default

In block2: All instance of class Car will be created with an odometer_reading = 0

The use of the blocks depends on the business logic of your application

Example: Let's say you have an application for selling cars.
If you sell only new cars (by default they have 0 odometer_reading) using block 2 or 3 method is more comprehensive method for you as you do not need to insert any value for the odometer_reading.

In case you are selling old used cars then every time you register a car to your system you need to enter the value.

In case you sell both used and new cards then block 2 method won't work for you.